# Can you extend the unit speed vector field on a circle embedded in the Möbius band to the whole Möbius band?

Tags: differential-geometry

I found in my old notes that if a vector field $X$ is defined on a simply connected subset $U \subset M$, it can be extended to a vector field $\overline X$ on $M$ using bump functions. For a counterexample in the non-simply connected case, I had that the unit-speed vector field on a circle embedded in the Möbius band cannot be extended. However, I think that I can construct such an extension as follows.

First, a drawing of the idea
(in red, I depict the vector field on the embedded circle. In blue, the extension):

[image: In red, the vector field on the embedded circle. In blue, the extension]

Done explicitly, I first cover the Möbius band with charts

$$ \phi: M \supset U_\phi \rightarrow (0,1) \times (0,1),$$
$$ \psi: M \supset U_\psi \rightarrow (0,1) \times (0,1)$$

having the transition function:

\begin{align}
\psi\circ\phi^{-1}: \left(\left(0,\frac14\right)\cup\left(\frac34,1\right)\right) \times (0,1) & \rightarrow \left(\left(0,\frac14\right)\cup\left(\frac34,1\right)\right) \times (0,1)
\end{align}

\begin{align}
(x,y) & \mapsto \begin{cases}\left(\frac14-x, y\right)\qquad\mathrm{if}\quad x\in\left(0,\frac14\right) \\ 
\left(\frac74-x, 1-y\right)\qquad\mathrm{if}\quad x\in\left(\frac34,1\right).\end{cases}
\end{align}

Then, I embed the circle $C:\left[0, \frac 64\right] \rightarrow M$ by parametrizing it in the local charts

\begin{align}\phi \circ C : \underbrace{\left[ 0, \frac 64\right] \cap C^{-1}\left(\operatorname {im} C\cap U_\phi\right)}_{(0,1)}&\rightarrow (0,1)\times (0,1) \\
t &\mapsto \left(t,\frac 12\right)\end{align}

and
\begin{align}\psi \circ C : \underbrace{\left[ 0, \frac 64\right] \cap C^{-1}\left(\operatorname {im} C\cap U_\psi\right)}_{\left[0,\frac 14\right) \cup \left(\frac 34,\frac 64\right]}&\rightarrow (0,1)\times (0,1)\\
t &\mapsto \begin{cases}\left(\frac 14 - t,\frac 12\right) \qquad \mathrm{if}\quad t\in \left[0,\frac 14\right) \\ \left(\frac 74 - t,\frac 12\right) \qquad \mathrm{if}\quad t\in \left(\frac34,\frac 64\right] \end{cases}\end{align}

Then, if I’m not mistaken, the unit-speed vector field $X = dC\left(\frac \partial{\partial t}\right)$ is extended by the vector field $\overline X$ which is defined on $M$ by

$$d\phi (X) = \frac \partial{\partial x}$$
$$d\psi (X) = -\frac \partial{\partial x}$$

where $\frac \partial{\partial x}$ is the coordinate vector field corresponding to the first coordinate of $(0,1)\times (0,1)$ (the horizontal direction).

Comment: I think your notes are simply wrong. Also, you should explain what are the exact assumptions on $U$: if it is open, the claim is false, if it is closed, then state precisely what a vector field means in this case (smoothness of $X$).

Comment: @MoisheKohan are you saying that it is not possible in general to extend a vector field from a simply connected open subset $U$ to $M$? And that this may be possible if $U$ is closed depending on further assumptions on $X$?

Comment: Sanity check: Present the Mobius strip as a square with the vertical edges identified appropriately. Draw your vector field and proposed extension.

Comment: Yes, just try to extend the vector field $x^{-1}\partial_x$ from $(0,\infty)$ to the entire real line. If $U$ is closed and you correctly define vector fields on $U$ then the extension is always possible regardless of the topological properties of $U$.

Comment: @MoisheKohan but then you must mean that the extension is possible to some neighborhood of $U$, not to the entire ambient manifold $M$, right?

Comment: No, I meant the entire $M$. As I said, your notes are simply wrong.

Comment: @MoisheKohan I see. I first extend the vector field over a “dampening” neighborhood of $U$ and then by zero elsewhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in my comments, you should not trust your old notes. If you want to re-learn the subject, consider reading a textbook instead. Here is how to correct what is written in your notes.

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold, $A\subset M$ a subset. A (smooth) vector field on $A$ is a map $X: A\to TM$ such that:

1. $X(a)\in T_aM$ for all $a\in A$.
2. For every $a\in A$ there is a neighborhood $U_a$ of $a$ in $M$ and a (smooth) vector field $X_{U_a}$ on $U_a$ extending the restriction of $X$ to $U_a\cap A$.

Lemma. For every closed subset $A\subset M$ and every vector field $X$ on $A$, there exists an extension of $X$ to the entire $M$. (Simple connectivity of $A$ is irrelevant, but you have to assume that $A$ is closed.)

Proof. The complement $U:= M\setminus A$ is an open subset of $M$. Thus, we obtain an open cover ${\mathcal V}$ of $M$ consisting of the open subsets $U_a$ ($a\in A$) and of $U$. Since $M$ is [paracompact](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space), the open cover ${\mathcal V}$ of $M$ admits a locally finite refinement ${\mathcal W}$.  Each member of ${\mathcal W}$ is a subset of one of the members of ${\mathcal V}$. In particular, since $U$ is disjoint from $A$, there is a subset ${\mathcal W}'\subset {\mathcal W}$ which is an open cover of $A$ and such that each $W\in {\mathcal W}'$ is contained in some $U_a, a\in A$. In particular, for each $W\in {\mathcal W}'$ we have a vector field $X_W$ extending $X|_{W\cap A}$ (just restrict $X_{U_a}$ to $W$). For $W\in {\mathcal W}\setminus {\mathcal W}'$ take $X_W$ to be the zero vector field.
Now, let $\{\rho_W: W\in {\mathcal W}\}$ denote a partition of unity associated with the open cover ${\mathcal W}$ of $M$. For each $W\in {\mathcal W}$ define the vector field $Y_W$ on $M$ which equals $\rho_W X_W$ on $W$ and zero on $M\setminus W$. Lastly, set
$$
Y:= \sum_{W\in {\mathcal W}} Y_W.
$$
This is a vector field on $M$ extending $X$. qed

Remark. The same definition and the proof applies, more generally, to sections of vector bundles $E\to M$ defined on closed subsets $A\subset M$.